# android - navigation tabs - swipe tabs(fixed tabs)

Tags: android, tabs, swipe

As I am new to android, I want to implement swipe tabs (fixed tabs).
My requirement is to implement two tabs in the tab with Google map and other tab with list view.

[image]

above mentioned image manner i want to implement

Thanks in  Advance....

Comment: So what's your question? What have you tried so far?

Comment: as android provided sample example we have implemented. we achieved it but we want to implement one tab with Google map and another tab with list view like above image.....

Comment: @BothsaVenu As you have already implemented it then you should put a bit more effort for maps. You just have to open and load the fragment on click of the Maps tab only.

Comment: thank you for suggestion.. i will try to implement if i got then i will ping you mean while if there is any way try to post me..